# What happens if in new version of an iOS app entire code changes(all classes, storyboard changed, No database in old app)? will it work or crash?

Tags: ios, iphone

What if I want to do an iOS app version update with entirely new code, new project but same bundle identifier and certificates? Assume that old app doesn't have database but has some core data mechanism... Will it work or just keep crashing?

Comment: *Why* should it crash? The OS does not give a **** about the changes. The updated app is a new binary executable and that is it. As long as *you* handle previous data that is lying around the Documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, Apple does not care how much of your code changes between releases. So yes, this should be possible.

Also, be advised that core data *is* a database, it is backed by an sqlite store. I would not advise trying to interact with that database in the new app; it *is* possible but very prone to problems.

Comment: If your database model has certain small changes only, it can be updated automatically. For bigger changes, you add code to update the database.

Comment: thanks people... It always works.. and yes its true. Apple doesn't give *** about code and classes... Unless and until your resources(images, sqlite file) don't mess up it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The update is not a problem, Apple cares only about the ID.

Core data is database, so I would make sure to delete the DB with the update, if I really don't need it anymore.

Whether the app keeps crashing depends on the reason why it is crashing before the update. If it is a code issue, it will no longer crash. If it is e.g. an issue with files that the new app uses as well, the it will keep crashing. But if the app is really completely new, it is hard to imagine such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the new version App should avoid to access the old data, this may cause crash, instead consider clean up the old data or transform them into the correct form.